# Is there any security implications of calling a workflow from power apps using service account connector

Tags: power-automate, powerapps-forms

I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ts-ggDAy7IQ&t=18s which shows how we can call a workflow from power apps using another user context (for example using service account context which have full control on the SharePoint site). this can allow us to run some actions in elevated privileges. but what is the security implications of doing so? for example can any user call this workflow on behave of the service account context outside the power app? or we can be sure that this flow will only be called from the related power apps?? can not a user create his/her own power app and call this workflow the way they want so they can perform actions on behave on the service account which will create a security vulnerability ?